# Convert bin model to pickle

Tags: gensim, pickle

I trained a word2vec model using Gensim library which is of type .bin

Q1: can we convert this trained model in bin format to pickle?

Q2: would it speed up the execution time?

Comment: I checked how to use pickle module but most of the articles on this talks about scikit-learn: save and restore models.. is it same thing if model is trained using gensim library

Answer (score 1):

Pickle is not a format but a protocol to serialize a python object to binary format.
[In the documentation of gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html#gensim.utils.SaveLoad), you can read they actually use pickle for serializing to binary format.

You can of course use pickle library instead of the `.save` method in gensim, but it will be exactly the same, since gensim already use pickle. I would recommend you to use `.save` method however, because gensim likely has better way to handle the hierarchical structure and dependencies of your model.